# PDF - Prevent/nag the print action if the user has not filled in a form correctly

Tags: pdf, printing

## Situation

The company signs a contract with a client. Part of the contract requires that the client provides some access details to it's own server.

The contract is sent in .doc format to the client, and the client needs to fill in the contract with it's information, sign it, print it, scan it and send it back via e-mail so that we can work with it, until the physical contract arrives via courier.

## Issue

With the contract, there is also sent a note indicating that all the information must be filled in electronically, and then printed. However, most of the clients simply print the contract, then fill it in by hand before scanning, which makes the retrieval of the information contained within quite difficult sometimes.

## Solution

The only one we had thinked about is to send the contract in a PDF format, containing a fill-able form and a script that will prevent the user from printing the document if the form is not filled in (or at least nag the printing process with some messages if it is not possible to prevent printing)

## Question

1. Is it even possible? If so, where can I find examples/resources for this?
2. Are there other (better) options available?

(I have located some resources regarding scripting: [PDFScripting.com](http://www.pdfscripting.com/) and [JavaScript for Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html) from Adobe. Any other suggestions?)

Comment: The best solution I can think of is using Javascript for Acrobat, which you already mentioned. However if the user disables javascript in Acrobat Reader you are back to square 1...

Comment: I am not looking for a 100% foolprof solution... I can live with several contracts being handwritten now and then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you could use Adobe-JavaScript for this.

The sample code from Adobe, [Enforcing Required Fields](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Enforcing_Required_Fields-16435.html), may help.

From that page, the code you have to include in your PDF file will look like this:

```
f = getField(event.target.name)
if (f.value.length == 0)
{    
   f.setFocus()    
   //Optional Message - Comment out the next line to remove
   app.alert("This field is required. Please enter a value.")
}
```

You will need to add this code to your PDF files using a PDF processing library of your choice, add a print button to your form and put this verification before printing. The code should be wrapped in a Javascript action object.

You can also add this code as an action event of your document, specifically in a ["will print" event](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/print/entering-document-actions).

The "will print" event is set in an entry called WP in the catalog (root) object of the PDF file. From the PDF specification:

**TABLE 8.47 Entries in the document catalog’s additional-actions dictionary**
**Key:** WP
**Type:** dictionary
**Description:** (Optional; PDF 1.4) A JavaScript action to be performed before printing a document. (The name WP stands for “will print.”)

Comment: Great! I don't have time today for this, but it definitely looks like the right track to follow. Thanks a bunch!